# UWP is not showing correct scale and resolution when run on local machine

Tags: c#, uwp

I have build a UWP project in 12" tablet size (which I chose from options provided when I design the UI in designer)

[image]

However when I run the application, it is shown too big on my screen, my design could not shown completely on the screen.

For example, I have 2 buttons in my design form top to down, only the top one is shown but the below one is missing due to my screen is not big enough to show them. But my laptop screen is 15.6", and previously the program was run in another desktop with a 24" monitor and it shows correctly.

Is there anything I can do to change the resolution/scale of my application on the laptop screen? My laptop resolution is 1920x1080.

Thank you.

Comment: Either set a bunch of visual states, or put everything in a Viewbox.

Comment: Could also use a grid with rows of height set with the "*" method and have the buttons fill their row.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil Thanks will try that one!

Comment: @KennyWitham I see, so using a grid as the container. Mine was currently the Relative Panel, will try with grid, thanks!

Comment: @Corene Did you hard-code a size in for the buttons inside each button?

Comment: @KennyWitham Yes, I set the height and width for every button, text blocks and text box.

Comment: @KennyWitham I think its the resolution problem... Its still not showing the correct resolution, I think the resolution is 2160*1440 for 12" 150% scale, my laptop resolution is only 1920*1080, how do I change the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the resolution is 2160*1440 for 12" 150% scale, my laptop resolution is only 1920*1080, how do I change the resolution?

Windows automatically selects a scale factor for each display based on its DPI (dots-per-inch) and the viewing distance of the device. So that the scale factor is defined by the windows. Details please reference [Effective pixels and scale factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design#effective-pixels-and-scale-factor).

Users can override the default value and by going to `Settings >System> Display > Scale and layout` settings page. You could change the scale to 100% for your laptop.